# MTG What happens if the player can't fulfil Iridescent Drake ability

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Iridescent Drake](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIridescent%20Drake%5d) has the ability: "When Iridescent Drake enters the battlefield, put target Aura card from a graveyard onto the battlefield under your control attached to Iridescent Drake."

Can I play Iridescent Drake if there's no Aura in any graveyard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there's no valid target for the ability, nothing happens. After Iridescent Drake enters the battlefield, you put that triggered ability on the stack. This process includes choosing targets, and if you can't choose any valid targets, you simply don't put the ability on the stack.

The [triggered ability rules](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Triggered_ability) describe exactly how this works:

> - **603.3.** Once an ability has triggered, its controller puts it on the stack as an object that’s not a card the next time a player would receive priority. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> - **603.3d** The remainder of the process for putting a triggered ability on the stack is identical to the process for casting a spell listed in rules 601.2c–d. **If a choice is required when the triggered ability goes on the stack but no legal choices can be made for it, or if a rule or a continuous effect otherwise makes the ability illegal, the ability is simply removed from the stack.**
> - [**601.2c**](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Casting_spells) The player announces his or her choice of an appropriate player, object, or zone for each target the spell requires. [...]